Unable to Install pytorch-forecasting: No module named 'distutils' Error
When I try running pip install pytorch-forecasting in my VSCode terminal, I get the error that there is No module named 'distutils'.
To preface this, PyTorch is already installed, and pytorch-forecasting is installed on Anaconda using conda install pytorch-forecasting pytorch>=1.7 -c pytorch -c conda-forge.
I've seen the solution of pip install setuptools. I ran the command to install setuptools successfully on my terminal, but it did not get rid of the No module named 'distutils' error.
I need help to bypass the "No module named 'distutils'" error so that I can install the pytorch-forecasting package.
